# Task :app:validateSigningRelease FAILED (not found for signing config 'release'.) using react native

Tags: react-native

what can i do when keystore is already available in my app but error is coming like this (not found for signing config 'release'.)????? using react native
**Task :app:validateSigningRelease FAILED**

Comment: Question is not clear and seems to be copy pasted error without proper explanation. Prefer explaining problem in title and description to explain in detail with relevant code or error. If possible, steps to replicate properly considering it doesn't get large, in that case, consider creating a repo and link in description appropriately!

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the steps of the [official docs for releasing signed APK's](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android) it should work correctly.

Without any code is hard, but off the top of my head I think your problem may be on your app/build.gradle (android -> app -> build.gradle

In this code section you should have the following if you are going to release:

```
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
```

Notice that in realease -> signingConfig the configuration is **signingConfigs.release**